# How to make the response object that another ViewController's post request returns append to a TableViewController with Siesta Swift

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

I am a Swift beginner so apologies. With Siesta, I want to make a post request in a ViewController and then have the Entry object the request returns added to the TableViewController. In my ViewController:

```
EntryAPI.sharedInstance.addEntry()
```

The API code:

```
 func addEntry()  -> Request {
        return newEntry().request(.post, json:["foo": "bar"])
    }

func newEntry() -> Resource {
        return service
            .resource("/entry")
    }
```

After the post request the ViewController does an unwind segue to the TableViewController, of course before the post request completes. I am not sure where in the code I would take the response and call a function in the TableViewController that appends the new Entry object to the entry list.

I am not sure if I should pass the new Entry object from the `addEntry()` function to the TableViewController with `onSuccess()` or if the TableViewController can have the `newEntry()` resource and know when the post request completes. I am not sure if I am going about this in the right way either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an observer for your request (https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/observers/) and when it completes update the data in your tableview.

Comment: Thanks. So to clarify, am I adding the TableViewController to be an observer or the ViewController? If the ViewController, how can I send the new Entry object to the TableViewController if the segue happens before it completes?

Comment: observer to your post request in Siesta to some external API.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to add the `newEntry()` resource to the TableViewController and change the API method:

```
func addEntry()  -> Request {
        let resource = newEntry()
        return resource.load(using: resource.request(.post, json:
            ["foo": "bar"]).onSuccess {_ in})
    }
```

Now `resourceChanged` function will be called where I can handle the response object. Answer was in the documentation.